# After upgrade to Xenial scanner problem

Tags: 16.04, samsung, scanner, sane, simplescan

I upgraded recently from Trusty to Xenial ; got one big glitch concerning my scanner that only does work sometimes now, with apps crashing, or just not recognizing the scanner anymore as it used to, and working eventually after lot of trying.

I did looked around to get some logs you can find below, hope it helps to give some pointer, I really don't know what I could try there.
The scanner's name is "Samsung multifonction CLX 3185 FW"

Simple scan :

```
[quote]utilisateur@utilisateur-H81M-S2H:~$ export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255
utilisateur@utilisateur-H81M-S2H:~$ simple-scan
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of dll to 255.
[dll] sane_init: SANE dll backend version 1.0.13 from sane-backends 1.0.25git
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `./dll.d'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `/etc/sane.d/dll.d'
[dll] sane_get_devices
[dll] load: searching backend `xerox_mfp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `xerox_mfp'
[dll] init: backend `xerox_mfp' is version 1.0.13
[dll] load: searching backend `v4l' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: couldn't find backend `v4l' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: searching backend `umax1220u' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax1220u.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax1220u.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `umax1220u'
[dll] init: backend `umax1220u' is version 1.0.2
[dll] load: searching backend `umax' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `umax'
[dll] init: backend `umax' is version 1.0.45
[dll] load: searching backend `u12' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-u12.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-u12.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `u12'
[dll] init: backend `u12' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `teco3' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco3.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco3.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `teco3'
[dll] init: backend `teco3' is version 1.0.1
[dll] load: searching backend `teco2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco2.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco2.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `teco2'
[dll] init: backend `teco2' is version 1.0.10
[dll] load: searching backend `teco1' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco1.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-teco1.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `teco1'
[dll] init: backend `teco1' is version 1.0.10
[dll] load: searching backend `tamarack' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-tamarack.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-tamarack.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `tamarack'
[dll] init: backend `tamarack' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `sp15c' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sp15c.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sp15c.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `sp15c'
[dll] init: backend `sp15c' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `snapscan' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-snapscan.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-snapscan.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `snapscan'
[dll] init: backend `snapscan' is version 1.4.53
[dll] load: searching backend `sm3840' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sm3840.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sm3840.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `sm3840'
[dll] init: backend `sm3840' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `sm3600' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sm3600.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sm3600.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `sm3600'
[dll] init: backend `sm3600' is version 1.0.6
[dll] load: searching backend `sharp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sharp.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sharp.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `sharp'
[dll] init: backend `sharp' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `sceptre' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sceptre.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-sceptre.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `sceptre'
[dll] init: backend `sceptre' is version 1.0.10
[dll] load: searching backend `s9036' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-s9036.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-s9036.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `s9036'
[dll] init: backend `s9036' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `rts8891' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-rts8891.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-rts8891.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `rts8891'
[dll] init: backend `rts8891' is version 1.0.2401
[dll] load: searching backend `ricoh' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ricoh.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ricoh.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `ricoh'
[dll] init: backend `ricoh' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `qcam' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-qcam.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-qcam.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `qcam'
[dll] init: backend `qcam' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `plustek' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-plustek.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-plustek.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `plustek'
[dll] init: backend `plustek' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `pixma' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `pixma'
[dll] init: backend `pixma' is version 1.0.17
[dll] load: searching backend `pie' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pie.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pie.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `pie'
[dll] init: backend `pie' is version 1.0.9
[dll] load: searching backend `niash' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-niash.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-niash.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `niash'
[dll] init: backend `niash' is version 1.0.1
[dll] load: searching backend `nec' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-nec.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-nec.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `nec'
[dll] init: backend `nec' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `mustek_usb2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `mustek_usb2'
[dll] init: backend `mustek_usb2' is version 1.0.10
[dll] load: searching backend `mustek_usb' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek_usb.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek_usb.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `mustek_usb'
[dll] init: backend `mustek_usb' is version 1.0.18
[dll] load: searching backend `mustek' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-mustek.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `mustek'
[dll] init: backend `mustek' is version 1.0.138
[dll] load: searching backend `microtek2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-microtek2.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-microtek2.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `microtek2'
[dll] init: backend `microtek2' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `microtek' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-microtek.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-microtek.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `microtek'
[dll] init: backend `microtek' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `matsushita' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-matsushita.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-matsushita.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `matsushita'
[dll] init: backend `matsushita' is version 1.0.7
[dll] load: searching backend `magicolor' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-magicolor.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-magicolor.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `magicolor'
[dll] init: backend `magicolor' is version 1.0.1
[dll] load: searching backend `ma1509' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ma1509.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ma1509.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `ma1509'
[dll] init: backend `ma1509' is version 1.0.3
[dll] load: searching backend `lexmark' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-lexmark.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-lexmark.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `lexmark'
[dll] init: backend `lexmark' is version 1.0.32
[dll] load: searching backend `leo' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-leo.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-leo.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `leo'
[dll] init: backend `leo' is version 1.0.11
[dll] load: searching backend `kvs20xx' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kvs20xx.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kvs20xx.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `kvs20xx'
[dll] init: backend `kvs20xx' is version 1.0.2
[dll] load: searching backend `kvs1025' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kvs1025.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kvs1025.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `kvs1025'
[dll] init: backend `kvs1025' is version 1.0.5
[dll] load: searching backend `kodakaio' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kodakaio.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kodakaio.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `kodakaio'
[dll] init: backend `kodakaio' is version 1.0.2
[dll] load: searching backend `kodak' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kodak.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-kodak.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `kodak'
[dll] init: backend `kodak' is version 1.0.7
[dll] load: searching backend `ibm' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ibm.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-ibm.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `ibm'
[dll] init: backend `ibm' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `hs2p' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hs2p.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hs2p.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hs2p'
[dll] init: backend `hs2p' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `hpljm1005' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpljm1005.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpljm1005.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hpljm1005'
[dll] init: backend `hpljm1005' is version 1.0.1
[dll] load: searching backend `hp5590' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp5590.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp5590.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp5590'
[dll] init: backend `hp5590' is version 1.0.7
[dll] load: searching backend `hp5400' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp5400.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp5400.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp5400'
[dll] init: backend `hp5400' is version 1.0.3
[dll] load: searching backend `hp4200' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp4200.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp4200.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp4200'
[dll] init: backend `hp4200' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `hp3500' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp3500.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp3500.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp3500'
[dll] init: backend `hp3500' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `hpsj5s' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpsj5s.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpsj5s.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hpsj5s'
[dll] init: backend `hpsj5s' is version 1.0.3
[dll] load: searching backend `hp3900' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp3900.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp3900.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp3900'
[dll] init: backend `hp3900' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `hp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hp'
[dll] init: backend `hp' is version 1.0.8
[dll] load: searching backend `gt68xx' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-gt68xx.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-gt68xx.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `gt68xx'
[dll] init: backend `gt68xx' is version 1.0.84
[dll] load: searching backend `genesys' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-genesys.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-genesys.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `genesys'
[dll] init: backend `genesys' is version 1.0.2506
[dll] load: searching backend `fujitsu' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `fujitsu'
[dll] init: backend `fujitsu' is version 1.0.126
[dll] load: searching backend `epsonds' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epsonds.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epsonds.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `epsonds'
[dll] init: backend `epsonds' is version 1.0.35
[dll] load: searching backend `epson2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epson2.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epson2.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `epson2'
[dll] init: backend `epson2' is version 1.0.124
[dll] load: searching backend `epjitsu' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epjitsu.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epjitsu.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `epjitsu'
[dll] init: backend `epjitsu' is version 1.0.28
[dll] load: searching backend `dmc' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-dmc.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-dmc.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `dmc'
[dll] init: backend `dmc' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `dell1600n_net' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `dell1600n_net'
[dll] init: backend `dell1600n_net' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `coolscan3' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-coolscan3.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-coolscan3.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `coolscan3'
[dll] init: backend `coolscan3' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `coolscan' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-coolscan.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-coolscan.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `coolscan'
[dll] init: backend `coolscan' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `cardscan' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-cardscan.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-cardscan.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `cardscan'
[dll] init: backend `cardscan' is version 1.0.2
[dll] load: searching backend `canon_dr' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon_dr.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon_dr.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `canon_dr'
[dll] init: backend `canon_dr' is version 1.0.49
[dll] load: searching backend `canon630u' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon630u.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon630u.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `canon630u'
[dll] init: backend `canon630u' is version 1.0.1
[dll] load: searching backend `canon' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-canon.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `canon'
[dll] init: backend `canon' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `bh' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-bh.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-bh.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `bh'
[dll] init: backend `bh' is version 1.0.4
[dll] load: searching backend `as6e' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-as6e.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-as6e.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `as6e'
[dll] load: searching backend `artec_eplus48u' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `artec_eplus48u'
[dll] init: backend `artec_eplus48u' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `artec' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-artec.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-artec.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `artec'
[dll] init: backend `artec' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `avision' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-avision.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-avision.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `avision'
[dll] init: backend `avision' is version 1.0.297
[dll] load: searching backend `apple' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-apple.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-apple.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `apple'
[dll] init: backend `apple' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `agfafocus' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-agfafocus.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-agfafocus.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `agfafocus'
[dll] init: backend `agfafocus' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `abaton' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-abaton.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-abaton.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `abaton'
[dll] init: backend `abaton' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `net' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-net.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-net.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `net'
[dll] init: backend `net' is version 1.0.25
[dll] load: searching backend `xerox_mfp-smfp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp-smfp.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp-smfp.so.1' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp-smfp.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp-smfp.so.1' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: couldn't find backend `xerox_mfp-smfp' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: searching backend `hpaio' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpaio.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpaio.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `hpaio'
[dll] init: backend `hpaio' is version 1.0.0
[dll] load: searching backend `smfp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1' (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `smfp'
[dll] init: backend `smfp' is version 1.0.1
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 (LTS) to 16.04 (LTS) with the Samsung C480W all-in-one printer. Printing was always fine, but the scanner needed a uninstall/reinstall with the official driver package from the [Samsung setup page](https://www.samsungsetup.com/TS/Client/en/Install.html):

```
sudo ./unistall.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

See the corresponding [article on my blog](https://qrys.ch/installing-the-samsung-c480w-printer-on-ubuntu-linux/#update-when-scanning-after-upgrade-does-not-work).